# python re how to Extract fields use findall()?

Tags: python

```
                            staffs：
                            50 - 100


                            year_turnover：
                            0

                            url：
                            http://www.chinaanigu.com
```

how to re.findall() year_turnover: after and staffs: after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stripping all the unwanted escape characters, follwing regexs' can be applied to extract the required data:

```
import re

sample_text = """
staffs:
50 - 100

year_turnover:
0

url:
http://www.chinaanigu.com
"""

print re.findall(r"staffs:\n(.*)", sample_text) # catches anything followed by staffs:
>>> ['50 - 100']
print re.findall(r"year_turnover:\n(.*)", sample_text)
>>> ['0']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = """
                            staffs:
                            50 - 100


                            year_turnover:
                            0

                            url:
                            http://www.chinaanigu.com
"""
b = re.findall("staffs:\s+(\d.+\d)", a)
c = re.findall("year_turnover:\s+(\d)", a)
print(b)
print(c)
```